# Set a currentPoint for an ArrayList of Points in Java

Tags: java, point

I am a beginner to Java and am currently trying to make a basic text based game. Using 4 classes: `Main`, `Character`, `World` and `Constructor`, I have setup a map system in which there are 5 `ArrayList<Point>`s defined as:

```
public class Constructor {
    //Make Worlds
    World desktopSize = new World(15, 15);
    World laptopSize = new World(10,10);
    World routerSize = new World(10, 5);
    World dlTravelSpace = new World(3,1);
    World dlrTravelSpace = new World(1, 3);
}
```

And `World`s being created as:

```
public class World {
    private int x, y;
    private String direction;
    private int index;
    ArrayList<Point> mapSize = new ArrayList();
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    public World(int x, int y){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < y; j++) {
                mapSize.add(new Point(i + 1, j + 1));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the `Character` class I set all attributes using the method:

```
 public void setCharacter(String charClass, Point currentPoint) {
    if (charClass.equals("warrior")) {
        setName("Sparky");
        setLevel(1);
        setHp(100);
        setAttack(50);
        setDefense(20);
        setSpeed(10);
        //setSkills();
        setBackPackSpace(15);
        //setInventory();
        setCredits(1000);
        setCurrentPoint(10, 8);
    } else if (charClass.equals("ranged")) {
        setName("Sparky");
        setLevel(1);
        setHp(90);
        setAttack(60);
        setDefense(10);
        setSpeed(12);
        //setSkills();
        setBackPackSpace(14);
        //setInventory();
        setCredits(950);
        setCurrentPoint(10, 8);
    } else if (charClass.equals("tank")) {
        setName("Sparky");
        setLevel(1);
        setHp(110);
        setAttack(40);
        setDefense(30);
        setSpeed(9);
        //setSkills();
        setBackPackSpace(16);
        //setInventory();
        setCredits(1050);
        setCurrentPoint(10, 8);
    }
}
```

When I call the `setCharacter` method I use:

```
if (player.getCharClass().equals("warrior") || 
    player.getCharClass().equals("ranged") || 
    player.getCharClass().equals("tank")) {
  System.out.println("Class " + player.getCharClass() + " selected!");
  System.out.println("");
  player.setCharacter(player.getCharClass(), 
  player.getCurrentPoint());
} else {
  System.out.println("Invalid class selected. Please restart and try 
again.");
  System.exit(0);
}
```

However when I run the code it returns the following error:

```
Error:(34, 13) java: method setCurrentPoint in class Character cannot be 
applied to given types;
required: java.awt.Point
found: int,int
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

The error seems to be occuring at

```
 public void setCharacter(String charClass, Point currentPoint) {
    if (charClass.equals("warrior")) {
        setName("Sparky");
        setLevel(1);
        setHp(100);
        setAttack(50);
        setDefense(20);
        setSpeed(10);
        //setSkills();
        setBackPackSpace(15);
        //setInventory();
        setCredits(1000);
        setCurrentPoint(10, 8);
```

At

```
setCurrentPoint(10, 8);
```

The setCurrentPoint method is

```
public void setCurrentPoint(Point currentPoint) {
    this.currentPoint = currentPoint;
}
```

My problem is: How can I set the point attribute of the character so that they are at (10, 8) in world desktopSize. On creation

Comment: According to the error you are only passing a String to the setCharacter method. Can you post the code where you call setCharacter?

Comment: @MikeBruesch Updated question with the call

Comment: That setCharacter call looks right. Is that the line that throws the error? I'm thinking we might not have all the info we need to help answer your question.

Comment: I updated the setCharacter call cause i realized what the error in that was now its saying that setCurrentPoint in the method itself is incorrect due to the values 10, 8 being ints and it requires a point

Comment: @MikeBruesch I do not know how to pass 10, 8 as a point rather than int, int. Sorry for the mislead

Comment: Update your question with the new issue. Also post the code that is throwing the error please.

Comment: @MikeBruesch Updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `setCurrentPoint` method is not shown here but based on the error I'll assume it's something like

```
public void setCurrentPoint(Point somePoint) {...}
```

You are trying to call the method with two ints (10 and 8) so the error is thrown. You are being passed a `Point` object in the `setCharacter` method called `currentPoint`. Is this the `Point` object you want to set as the current Point? If so, you should call `setCurrentPoint` as follows:

```
setCurrentPoint(currentPoint);
```

If you want 10 and 8 hardcoded as the coordinates then you can create a new `Point` object with those values and send to the `setCurrentPoint` method:

```
setCurrentPoint(new Point(10,8));
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Whoops my bad I misunderstood which setCurrentPoint to post. I have updated with the set method. I would hardcode it but I would like to update it later on when I make the movement mechanic

Comment: And the points are already created in the Constructor class. I just wanna attribute a point to a character.